# Button click not logging object output to console in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue. I am trying to see the output of a function in the console before emitting it to the parent component. But the function doesn't output anything to the console.

Here's my code

AddTask.vue

```
template>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="add-form">
        <div class="form-control">
        <label>Task</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="text" name="text" placeholder="Add Task" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
        <label>Day & Time</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            v-model="day"
            name="day"
            placeholder="Add Day & Time"
        />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control form-control-check">
        <label>Set Reminder</label>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="reminder" name="reminder" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save Task" class="btn btn-block" />
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: 'AddTask',
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
            day: '',
            reminder: false,
        }
    },
    method: {
        onSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if (!this.text) {
                alert('Please add a task')
                return
            }

            const newTask = {
                id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
                text: this.text,
                day: this.day,
                reminder: this.reminder,
            }

            console.log(newTask)
            //this.$emit('add-task', newTask)

            this.text = ''
            this.day = ''
            this.reminder = false
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.add-form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.form-control label {
  display: block;
}

.form-control input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.form-control-check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-control-check label {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-control-check input {
  flex: 2;
  height: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Please can someone help me figure out what is not right in this code snippet, I would really appreciate.

Comment: method -> methods. Notice the 's'. Also if you're just learning Vue, might be worth just starting with the composition API. Using composition api you can just create functions and use them. But, just adding the 's' so you have methods should get you in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Rob Louie spotted in the comment, the 's' was missing from the methods. So the code snippet for that segment becomes

```
<script>
export default{
    name: 'AddTask',
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
            day: '',
            reminder: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if (!this.text) {
                alert('Please add a task')
                return
            }

            const newTask = {
                id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
                text: this.text,
                day: this.day,
                reminder: this.reminder,
            }

            console.log(newTask)
            //this.$emit('add-task', newTask)

            this.text = ''
            this.day = ''
            this.reminder = false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```